# R random vector generator

Tags: r, self-study, monte-carlo, computational-statistics

> Create an R function generating ordered pairs x,y sampled from the two
>   dimensional distribution whose pdf is of the form $f(x,y)=cxy$, where
>   $0<x,y<1$, and $c$ is a constant to be determined.

Integrating the pdf, I can determine that:

$$\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 c \, xy \, dx \, dy = 1 \Rightarrow c=4$$

Edit:
@Flounderer already suggested me how to create a random vector generator, but need to create a different one for the same density, what should I do?

Comment: Are x and y random uniform?

Comment: @MatthewDrury Not sure, but I suppose yes

Comment: askazy It looks to me like $f$ is a bivariate density, in which case you won't have a vector as output, since samples will consist of x,y pairs... @Matthew -- in which case, no, X&Y are *not* uniform.

Comment: @Glen_b: Yes, I wasn't sure how to interpret the question.

Comment: @Glen_b how could I generate these pairs $((X_1,Y_1),.....,(X_n,Y_n))$, I need to find c?

Comment: @askazy That would certainly be a good start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three general approaches are described in the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/randomvariate-from-2-dimensional-probability-distribution) but in your case it's easier.

You already found the joint density $f(x,y) = 4xy$. It factors into a function of $x$ and a function of $y$, so $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Therefore, you just need to generate $X$ and $Y$ separately. You can find their marginal distributions by integrating out to get $f_X(x) = 2x$ and $f_Y(y) = 2y$. To generate a random number from the distribution with pdf $f_X(x) = 2x$, you can generate a uniform random number and apply the inverse cdf. In this case, the cdf is $F_X(x) = \int_0^x f_X(t) dt = x^2$, so you can generate a random number from this distribution by doing $F_X^{-1}(U) = \sqrt{U}$ where $U \sim U(0,1)$. Similarly, you can generate a value of $Y$. Overall, $(X,Y) = (\sqrt{U}, \sqrt{V})$ where $U, V \sim U(0,1)$ are independent.

In R, a random vector from your distribution can be generated as

```
sqrt(runif(2))
```

To generate a matrix whose rows are $n$ random vectors sampled from your distribution you can do

```
sqrt(matrix(runif(n*2), ncol=2))
```

You can check graphically that this works.

Comment: Since the question requires an ordered pair I would return `apply(sqrt(matrix(runif(n*2), ncol=2)),1,sort)`

Comment: @Xi'an this serves to sort the lines?

Comment: @askazy: have you checked this command by yourself? If so, this should answer your question.

Comment: A question half beast, but how can I graphed the vector of random variables?

Comment: Semilion like this: `plot(sqrt(matrix(runif(n*2), ncol=2)))` to plot n ordered pairs generated from your distribution in the (x,y) plane.

Comment: @Flounderer If I need to create another generator, I can use the beta distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You've determined $c$, so you know the full pdf of the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$.  Now:

- Determine the pdf of the conditional distribution of $Y|X$, this amounts to finding the normalization factor you need for each value of X.
- Determine the pdf of the distribution of $X$.  This involves integrating out the effect of $Y$.
- First sample X, then sample Y conditioned on X.

Note that you cannot assume that $X$ and $Y$ are $U[0,1]$, though you will discover what they are by going through the procedure above.

Comment: It did not work, but if I assume that X and Y are $U[0,1]$, I can find $c$ calculating $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 cxy=1\rightarrow c=4$

Comment: Then you should edit your question to be more precise.  You are trying to generate data from a  two dimensional distribution whose pdf is of the form cxy.  This information was not in your question.  I will delete this answer once you edit.